# xpath: how to select nth option?

Tags: xpath

using xpath, how do you select the n-th option ?

```
<select>
<option></option>
<option></option>
</select>
```

/html/body/select/option[?]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what you have is correct:

for the 2nd option, use:

```
/html/body/select/option[2]
```

or

```
/html/body/select/option[position()=2]
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#location-paths

**Edit**

Note that the above assumes you have a structure like:

```
 <html>
  <body>
   <select>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
   </select>
  </body>
 </html>
```

If your select is inside of a parent other than body, then you either want to use something like:

```
/html/body/div[@class='header']/select/option[2]
```

or

```
//select/option[2]
```

Of course, since your select probably has a name attribute, you could use that, e.g.

```
//select[@name='myselect']/option[2]
```